# Регистрация вспомогательного метода в web.config ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Проблема очень простая. Создал вспомогательный метод в отдельном классе. Код ниже.

```
namespace Lesson5_AddTask.Infostructure
{
public static class HelperMethods
{
    public static MvcHtmlString Plus(this HtmlHelper helper, int a, int b)
    {
        TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("Label");
        int c = a + b;
        tag.SetInnerText((Convert.ToString(c)));
        return new MvcHtmlString(tag.ToString());
    }
}
}
```

Далее студия уже автоматом регит его в web.config

```
<add namespace="Lesson5_AddTask.Infostructure" />
```

Но он все равно не доступен во вьвере в @Html.

Работает только если вручную прописать вверху на вьюхе. Рабочий код ниже.

```
@using Lesson5_AddTask.Infostructure;

@{
Layout = null;
ViewBag.Title = "Index";

}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
    @Html.Plus(16, 25);
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Но всех этих костылей не хочется и хочу понять почему через веб.конфиг не работает???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась тем что просто нужно перезагрузить студию. Вот такой бок! Но всем все равно спасибо:)

Comment: Не забудьте поставить галку на решении. А вообще, у вас какая версия студии? У меня и без перезагрузки студии работает прекрасно. Я видел конечно эти ужасы, что нужно закрывать/открывать файл представления или студию перезапускать - но ничего такого не пришлось делать.

Comment: 15.6.4. Недавно обновлял

Comment: Практически такая же: 15.6.6, возможно, наличие решарпера играет роль?

Answer (score 1):

Не воспроизводится, хотя сделал всё в точности по описываемым вами действиям.

Мне вот что не нравится. Как-то вы вскользь описываете web.config.

Я не помню, чтобы в классическом asp.net mvc неймспейс грузился автоматом, вроде как я его руками всегда прописывал.

Во-вторых, прописывается он в который файл web.config - который глобальный или который в папке views лежит? [Правильно](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6723046/5752652) - который во views лежит.

А то может вы вообще ненароком правите файл в одном каталоге, а смотрите в другом? (Да-да, иногда такое случается дебажить несколько часов, а потом всплывает какая-то "мелочь")

Ради интереса создал пустой asp.net проект в 2017 студии, попробовал поправить дефолтный конфиг в папке views - всё прекрасно работает:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="WebApplication8" />
        <add namespace="WebApplication8.Extensions" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.web>
    <compilation>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

(Добавил руками только одну строчку - с `WebApplication8.Extensions`, я в папку Extensions обычно складываю методы расширения)

И могу ещё костыль предложить, не знаю вряд ли вам понравится, раз вы разобраться хотите: замените неймспейс на `System.Web.Mvc` ;)

Comment: Да, все записано в во View в веб конфиге! Проблема решилась тем что просто нужно перезагрузить студию. Вот такой бок! Но всем все равно спасибо:)  Костыль все равно попробую)))